# How to implement MVVM with Pages

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I trying to using the MVVM pattern in c# with Pages. I am trying to set the DataContext like so

```
    public partial class PageView : Page
    {
        public PageView()
        {
            BindingContext = new PageViewModel();

            //etc
```

But BindingContext doesn't exist.

What's the correct way to do this for pages?

Comment: I believe BindingContext is for .NET Maui, not WPF. These are similar but not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
DataContext = new PageViewModel();
```